# JDBC Class not found in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc

wrote some simple code to display contents of a database in console in Netbeans IDE, however when porting this code into Android Studio I receive many ClassNotFound errors, does anyone know how I can import the JDBC class into Android Studio or whether I have just made a coding error?

Code:

```
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
        String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

        //  Database credentials
        String USER = "root";
        String PASS = "";

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try{
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            //System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            //System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            String sql;
            sql = "SELECT id, first, last, username, password FROM Employees";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(rs.next() ){
                //Retrieve by column name
                int id  = rs.getInt("id");
                int age = rs.getInt("age");
                String first = rs.getString("first");
                String last = rs.getString("last");


                //Display values
                System.out.print("ID: " + id);
                System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
                System.out.print(", First: " + first);
                System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
            }
            //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
        }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
                if(stmt!=null)
                    stmt.close();
            }catch(SQLException se2){
            }// nothing we can do
            try{
                if(conn!=null)
                    conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
                se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
            //end try


        }
```

Errors:

```
02-16 07:25:40.285 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
02-16 07:25:40.285 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
02-16 07:25:40.285 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
02-16 07:25:40.285 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.example.georgetucker.youdecide.LoginActivity.loginButtonOnClick(LoginActivity.java:49)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mysql/jdbc/Driver
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     ... 18 more
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide-2, /system/lib]]
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-16 07:25:40.295 24180-24180/com.example.georgetucker.youdecide W/System.err:     ... 18 more
```

Thanks for looking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to write a simple app that reads data from a database. if that's the case, you shouldn't be considering mysql. use SQLite which comes with android which should be sufficient for most uses for local databases on your android phone.

But if you plan to make a real app, you will use mysql on the backend server and let android call it via http(s) and maybe if you need you'll store some of the retrieved data locally in your sqllite db. This is called the 3-tier architecture (and a design pattern called MVC is a good application of it). Your android app is mainly the presentation part, where the backend server is responsible for the logic and for database connection. Here is a simple presentation of how it works (and I suggest to read about it generally, you just need to get the idea):

[image]

If you're new to mobile programming and don't know how real world apps work (or how they are structured), I suggest you take the free , and actually fun, android  video courses developed by google on udacity (also see the gradle course) and you'll get the grasp of how to connect to something on the backend and get the data:

[udacity android online courses](https://www.udacity.com/courses/android)

Comment: Yeah, it's a college programming project that needs to be linked to a database (end project will be a small social network) so as I am adhering to tight time constraints I need the quickest solution to get my head around as well as it functioning in the real world, is there no way that JDBC could be implemented in this system as I have already been taught the syntax for it? Thanks :-)

Comment: I don't think so .. there are some things for web developers to install packages that act as a PHP and mysql server, but I don't believe that's what you need .. if you're in a hurry for a draft, you can postpone (or even ignore, although I don't advise) the backend part .. just make it all local, but use SQLite .. believe me it's easy and has very similar syntax to famous RDBM systems like mysql (the select is select anywhere, the weher clause, the ordereby, groupby .. all the same) .. you know mysql so you won't face any problem, just look at a simple tutorial and get going

Comment: see this for example .. seems a little long, but in a couple of hours you'll get all you need to access the DB: [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm) .. and when you need more understanding or concepts, re-surf the web ^_^

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely use this instead as it looks so much easier and less of a hassle, one last question which I couldn't quite find the answer for though, will it work with localhost server programs such as XAMPP and/or WAMPP?

Comment: I'll answer in multiple comments .. no, if use the approach to do everything locally on the android device (which is not actually a real app, just a sample), you don't need anything like xampp or wampp .. but if you choose to do it the right way, as an actual simple app, you can do the server side using php and mysql and use xampp or wampp to manage it, and the android app will contact the server using the internet (http) and get the data from it (not difficult by the way, read about androidhttpclient and json)

Comment: Real social media apps (simple or big like FB for example) usually stores the latest data in the local DB (sqlite) so that you can access latest updates offline .. You could ask your teacher or colleagues about the requirements to know which approach to use .. I'm just telling you cause you said it's a project not just a simple homework, so do it in a way that you'll most likely use in real life even it's simpler .. cause posting to stackoverflow means you enjoy programming and want to learn, so get the requirements and do it right without over complicating it .. sorry for the long answer ^_^

Comment: I understand now! Thanks for your time today, I better start programming now :P